# How do I alert on z score in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, alert, anomaly-detection

I have the following expression:

```
(avg_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[5m])) - (avg_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[48h])) / (stddev_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[48h]))
```

Detecting anomalies over a 48h interval. I am struggling to understand how I can write an alert that would be sent out when an anomaly is detected. Or am I totally wrong and this can be already employed as it will fire off when the anomaly is detected?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Try the following query for alerting:

```
abs(
  avg_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[5m])
  - 
  avg_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[48h])
)
/ stddev_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[48h])
> 3
```

It will alert (e.g. will return non-empty value) when the average series value over the last 5 minutes exceeds the average series value over the last 48 hours by more than 3x of standard deviation during the last 48 hours. In other words, if its' [z-score](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) exceeds 3. It is easy to adjust the threshold in the end of the query above. It is set to 3, but you can change it to any desired value.

Comment: This is great, thank you! I am now using this rule and also trying to find a way to test it properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72832048/unit-test-for-z-score-with-prometheus In case you have experience with unit testing alerts. It is a bit of a learning curve for me

Comment: I might have gotten somewhere with the test, but do you mind explain why 3x is the correct value to be used?

Comment: The 3x is just an example, which is frequently used in stats analysis  - see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule