# Unit test for z-score with Prometheus

Tags: unit-testing, prometheus, alerts

I have been experimenting a lot with writing unit tests for alerts as per this: `https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/unit_testing_rules/#alerts-yml`
I have some simple cases out, but now I am tackling rules that are less trivial. For example this:

```
abs(
  avg_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[1m])
  - 
  avg_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[3m])
)
/ stddev_over_time(my_metrics{service_name="aService"}[3m])
> 3
```

I have one file with the above rule and then this is in my test:

```
  - interval: 1m
      # Series data.
    input_series:
      - series: 'my_metrics{service_name="aService"}'
        values: '0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 '
    alert_rule_test:
      - eval_time: 3m
        alertname: myalert
        exp_alerts:
          - exp_labels:
              severity: warning
              service_name: aService
            exp_annotations:
                summary: "some text"
                description: "some other text"
```

I am not sure what my `series` should look like in order to test deviation from the mean. Is it even possible to test such rule?

Thank you

**EDIT**
I can have a succesful test if I set it `> 0` as opposed to `>3` I have tried to set a series of this sort:

```
'10+10x2 30+1000x1000'
```

but I cannot understand what would be the correct setup to have it triggered

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer, rather a tip from someone who spent quite some time on these tests. Did you know that apart from testing alert expressions, you can unittest PromQL expressions as well? See how it can be useful:

```yaml
evaluation_interval: 1m
tests:
- interval: 1m
  input_series:
  - series: test_metric
    values: 1 1 1 10 1 1 1

  promql_expr_test:
    - expr: avg_over_time(test_metric[1m])
      eval_time: 4m
      exp_samples:
        -  value: #5.5
    - expr: avg_over_time(test_metric[3m])
      eval_time: 4m
      exp_samples:
        - value: #3.25
    - expr: stddev_over_time(test_metric[3m])
      eval_time: 4m
      exp_samples:
        - value: #3.897114317029974
```

I've split your alert expression into three separate, simple parts. If you run this unittest, you will see the commented-out values in the error message. From here it is not difficult to join pieces together and see why the alert is not happening. You can use that to build a working sequence of values.

Comment: great, thank you so much! Slowly getting there and appreciating the ability to test alerts!

Comment: to clarify, I can trigger the alert as part of my unit test, I cannot have the values' series set in a way that would only alert when > 3.

Comment: @paranzana that's exactly what this is about. Basically, you need `2dn` and `3rd` values to be relatively low, while the first one has to be very high. With `PromQL` tests here you can see if a new sequence is close to desired values or not. Just run the test and look at the values in the error, that's it.

Comment: Fab, gotcha, thank you so much