# How to alert anomalies on network traffic jump with prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, alert, libvirt, prometheus-node-exporter, conntrack

We want to detect if a VM in our IaaS infra is under DDOS attack or not.

And We have several symptoms and metrics like: `node_nf_conntrack_entries`, `node_network_receive_packets_total` and also `libvirt_domain_interface_stats_receive_packets_total`

We do not want to have a `false positive` by setting a trigger point. Traffic > n then alert!

```
rate(libvirt_domain_interface_stats_receive_packets_total{host="x"}[5m])
```

[image]

```
rate(node_network_receive_packets_total{instance="y1"}[5m])
```

[image]

```
sum(node_nf_conntrack_entries_limit - node_nf_conntrack_entries) by (instance) < 1000
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare the average network traffic for the last 5 minutes to the average 5-minute network traffic 5 minutes ago. If it increases in 5 minutes by more than 10x, then alert:

```
(
  rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[5m])
    /
  rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[5m] offset 5m)
) > 10
```

See [docs for offset modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier).

This query may result in incorrect alerts though. For example, if the network traffic was close to zero and then it increased by more than 10x, but in absolute values it is still too small. This can be solved by adding a filter on too low network traffic. For example, the following query would alert only if the average per-second packet rate for the last 5 minutes is greater than 1000:

```
((
  rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[5m])
    /
  rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[5m] offset 5m)
) > 10)
  and
(
  rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[5m]) > 1000
)
```

This query can miss slow-changing DOS-attack when the network traffic grows at a rate lower than 10x per 5 minutes. This can be fixed by playing with `offset` value or by adding the absolute maximum packet rate, when the query should alert unconditionally. For example, the following query would alert unconditionally when the average packet rate for the last minute exceeds 100K/sec:

```
(
  ((
    rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[5m])
      /
    rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[5m] offset 5m)
  ) > 10)
    and
  (
    rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[5m]) > 1000
  )
)
  or
(
  rate(node_network_receive_packets_total[1m]) > 100000
)
```

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) for `and` and `or` operators.

Comment: Thank you very much @valyala, I follow your Medium posts too. 

What do you think of anomaly detection methods like Z-Score?

like: 
-   (https://blog.davidvassallo.me/2021/10/01/grafana-prometheus-detecting-anomalies-in-time-series/)
-   (https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2019/07/23/anomaly-detection-using-prometheus/)

Have you ever tried these? which method is better and more precise?

Comment: Both articles are very good in explaining on how to use Z-score for anomaly detection. They explain the same method actually - to alert when the Z-Score for the current metric value exceeds some threshold such as 3. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72793772/how-do-i-alert-on-z-score-in-prometheus

Answer (score 0):

To detect peak, you could use `max_over_time` function:

> max_over_time(range-vector): the maximum value of all points in the specified interval.

So you dont loose peak information when alertmanager do the query.